# Terminal app in live Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, live-usb

How can I open the terminal app in Ubuntu desktop booted from live cd(not intalled in hard drive) ?

Comment: Press CTRL-ALT-T simultaneously.

Comment: does that work in a live usb too?

Comment: You tell us. I'd say _"definitely yes, because there is no fundamental difference between a live CD and an actual installation with regard to the user interface."_ The live CD is designed to let you experience the actual look-and-feel of Ubuntu without installing it. It wouldn't make sense if it behaved differently. So just try it out :-)

Comment: It's a bit ago that I booted a live stick. Isn't there an icon on the desktop labelled "Terminal"? I'm not sure.

Comment: I did boot a liveUSB a few days ago, didn't had issue with ctrl-alt-T, nor ctrl-alt-F3. You are not able to launch a terminal window at all ?

Comment: so i have to install it alongside with windows to be able to use terminal?

Comment: Nooo! Just insert the CD or stick and boot from it. The whole purpose of the live CD (or stick) is that you do ___not___ have to install anything. Just boot from it, click "Just try" when asked and wait until a desktop comes up.

Comment: I will boot now the live usb, i just wanna make sure that the ctrl alt T works, because i will be offline while doing this

Comment: Fingers crossed! The good thing is: from that live USB you will be able to use the internet. Even via Wifi. It's just awesome.

Comment: yeah, for you it works...my computer don't have a built-in network adapter,and ubuntu don't recognise the Ovis Link adapter at all...

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that but at least now you know.

Answer (score 1):

2 options :

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to launch a term window

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>to<kbd>F6</kbd> to switch between tty

Comment: You, sir, are the real MVP;)